# How to return more than one item in prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have an algorithm for texts classification, working.
But, it returns me only 1 item in the prediction.
I would like to know how or if it is possible for it to return, 3 items with each new entry.

Train:

```
def train(texts, marcas):
    print("Training.....")
    tvect = TfidfTransformer()  # -> Obsolete <- TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=2, lowercase=False, preprocessor=None)
    # gera a vetorização (posição das palavras) para treino e predição
    count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None)
    vect_count_text = count_vect.fit_transform(texts)  # [vectorize_text(texto, tradutor) for texto in texts]
    vetoresDeTexto = tvect.fit_transform(vect_count_text)
    # Define o conjunto de dados X
    X = vetoresDeTexto  # np.array(vetoresDeTexto)
    # Define o conjunto de dados Y (labels)
    Y = np.array(marcas.tolist())
    # Define porcentagem do treino
    porcentagem_de_treino = 0.8
    # Separa o tamanho do treino a partir da porcentagem
    tamanho_do_treino = int(porcentagem_de_treino * len(Y))
    # O restante fica para a validacao
    tamanho_de_validacao = (len(Y) - tamanho_do_treino)
    # Separa os dados de treino
    treino_dados = X[0:tamanho_do_treino]
    # Separa as marcacoes de treino
    treino_marcacoes = Y[0:tamanho_do_treino]
    # Separa os dados de validacao
    validacao_dados = X[tamanho_do_treino:]
    # Separa as marcacoes de validacao
    validacao_marcacoes = Y[tamanho_do_treino:]
    print("Validacao Marcacoes: ")
    print(validacao_marcacoes)
    clf = LogisticRegression(class_weight=None)  # MultinomialNB() obtive 62% de acerto#GaussianNB()
    clf.fit(treino_dados, treino_marcacoes)
    # accuracy
    accuracy = clf.score(validacao_dados, validacao_marcacoes)
    file_name = 'train_data.pkl'
    cPickle.dump(clf, open(file_name, 'wb'))
    # fit_file = joblib.dump(clf, file_name)
    print("Accuracy: ")
    print("%.2f " % round(accuracy * 100) + "%\n")
    print("End of train...")
    predict(file_name, tvect, count_vect, treino_marcacoes, clf, treino_dados)
    # To get a fit_file
    # return fit_file
```

My predict code:

```
# to predict
def predict(fit, tvect, count_vect, y_test, clf, treinoX):
    print("\nPredict......")
    # new text to predict
    newTextToPredict = ["Just a new text to predict"]  # returns label J44

    new = count_vect.transform(newTextToPredict)
    # carrega o modelo treinado
    loaded_model = cPickle.load(open(fit, 'rb'))
    # faz a predição do novo texto de entrada
    result = loaded_model.predict(new)
    probs = clf.predict_proba(new)
    # precision_score(result, treinoY, average='samples')
    print(result)
```

Current output:

```
....
End of train...

Predict......
['Z000']
```

Is it possible that this output shows me the 3 most likely results?

Edit:

I tried to use the `predict_proba`, but I did not understand the results, it follows the output:

```
print(probs)

Predict......
['Z000']
[[0.00472141 0.00468681 0.00545111 0.00473597 0.00742972 0.00459905
  0.00472848 0.00471651 0.00830986 0.00472729 0.00537823 0.00539556
  0.00463566 0.00469166 0.00473597 0.00469889 0.00473122 0.00510944
  0.00475248 0.00475248 0.00472681 0.00465737 0.0046238  0.00538928
  0.0053852  0.00469701 0.00470745 0.0052977  0.00468655 0.00472517
  0.00601271 0.00540062 0.00471387 0.00471311 0.00471592 0.00468392
  0.00470526 0.00454069 0.00467939 0.00471795 0.00706113 0.00475248
  0.00470356 0.00451991 0.00473597 0.02389303 0.00472151 0.00475248
  0.00573423 0.00469125 0.00471707 0.00450935 0.00458729 0.00607249
  0.00556578 0.00661622 0.00747174 0.00528275 0.00469896 0.00527276
  0.00537725 0.0046918  0.00472592 0.00523041 0.00466061 0.00523704
  0.00535152 0.00471286 0.00456425 0.00473597 0.00466597 0.00475248
  0.00471198 0.00470039 0.00545111 0.00473597 0.0059082  0.00471645
  0.0050765  0.00536772 0.00469146 0.0047054  0.00583113 0.00556937
  0.00530836 0.00724415 0.00499861 0.00469217 0.00471454 0.00456743
  0.00473241 0.00468181 0.00545604 0.00471984 0.00466745 0.00606397
  0.01230014 0.00467241 0.00472609 0.00541621 0.00473499 0.00468064
  0.00472712 0.00470356 0.00497979 0.00453495 0.00469214 0.00668041
  0.00528025 0.00468329 0.00777699 0.00468618 0.00537916 0.00455798
  0.0046802  0.00468039 0.00534045 0.00466915 0.00521349 0.00465117
  0.00466947 0.00688886 0.00460614 0.00648024 0.00469368 0.00456555
  0.2215044  0.01841092 0.00594679 0.00467938 0.01121442 0.00537937
  0.00468134 0.00472712 0.00470844 0.00470639 0.00580538 0.00535144
  0.00473597 0.00465237 0.00577107 0.00539569 0.00472306 0.00538426
  0.00472506]]
```

Comment: Your `predict` function has the line `probs = clf.predict_proba(new)`, but you don't seem to be returning `probs` or otherwise using it. Have you tried looking at what that is?

Comment: @Acccumulation It was a test, I could not work with this data, I will do an update in the code.

Comment: @Henrique you can get the top3 classes according my last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print `probs`:

```
probs = clf.predict_proba(new)
print(probs)
```

You will get an array of **probabilities**. These probabilities' sum is equal to **1**.
Then you can choose the 3 most higher **valued** elements's indexes from this array.

```
top3_classes = np.argsort(probs)[:3]
```

These are the top 3 class labels indexes, you need.
So you can do then:

```
print(your_classes[top3_classes])
```

You got the top3 classes of the prediction.

Comment: Yes, I edited the code, I had tried, but I did not understand how to work with this `predict_proba`.

Comment: @Henrique This matrix seems to be the matrix of prob of possible classes, which are 145.

Comment: I've seen it but it returns me a lot of numbers, I do not know what they are or how to make them readable by showing the labels. Maybe that would be another question.

Comment: classes is for svm? Can't find the import.

Comment: @Henrique No, this is symbolic, these are classes that you passed to svm to predict a probabilities.

Comment: @Henrique like `classes = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grape']`

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change how you look at the problem. Instead of "give me the most likely class" you want for each class "does the data being to this class?". So many binary classifications instead of a single clarification with many classes

(Alternatively, that is a bit unclear, you might want to get the possibilities instead of argmax. In sklearn it is "predict_proba")